# Проверка на валидность украинского номера телефона (+380) PHP

Tags: php

Пожалуйста помогите подобрать регулярное выражение для проверки на валидность украинского номера телефона в формате +380ххххххххх.
вот пример с HTML5: pattern="^+380\d{3}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}$"
но на PHP не работает.

Comment: вот так - слэш добавьте `^\+380\d{7}$` - https://www.regex101.com/r/pV2qW7/1

Comment: Почему вы проверяете валидность только украинского телефона? А если вашим сервисом захочет воспользоваться иностранец?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
  $pattern = "/^\+380\d{3}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}$/";
  if(preg_match($pattern, "+380635290289")) echo "Валиден";
  else echo "Не валиден";
```

Comment: `\d{3}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}` = `\d{9}`

Comment: Согласен, в представленной автором вопроса форме регулярное выражение удобно, если потребуется добавить необязательные символы-разделители. Хотя ваш вариант, конечно, короче.

Answer (score 1):

А можно, если Вам это подходит, воспользоваться [плагином jQuery маскированного ввода](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

У себя в проекте задаю вот такую маску: `$("#phone").mask("+38 (999) 999-99-99");`, где $("#phone") - это поле ввода телефона. Под себя подпилите.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[\+]?3?[\s]?8?[\s]?\(?0\d{2}?\)?[\s]?\d{3}[\s|-]?\d{2}[\s|-]?\d{2}$/
```

- +380999999999
- +38(099)9999999
- +38(099)999 99 99
- +38(099) 999 99 99
- +3 8(099) 999 99 99
- +3 8 (099) 999 99 99
- +38(099)999-99-99
- +38(099) 999-99-99
- +38 (099) 999-99-99
- +3 8 (099) 999-99-99
- +3 8(099) 999-99-99